# Find how many WMTS tiles are loaded

Tags: qgis-3, wmts

I would like to know how many WMTS tiles are loaded when I navigate.
I use a WMTS feed which has a yearly limit of 2M transactions and I have to monitor my use of it to prevent reaching this limit, so knowing how many tiles are loaded depending on the size of my QGIS window would help.

Comment: Try this new plugin http://www.qgis.nl/2019/06/26/english-qgisnetworklogger-plugin-or-what-are-qgis-and-my-service-talking-about/?lang=en.

Comment: What operating system do you use?  If QGIS has internally cached a tile, and then pans back to that area and re-loads it from cache, does that count as another request?  Or only requests that are actually sent out on the network?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a network monitoring tool (see examples below), and configure it to filter on outgoing HTTP or HTTPS URL requests that include your WMTS server host and the WMTS tile request parameters:

- SERVICE=WMTS
- REQUEST=GetTile
- (the WMTS server host name(s) you are interested in)

Then log and/or count the matching results.

This would count all real requests, whether they are from QGIS, web browser, or elsewhere, and would NOT count re-use of cached tiles where the WMTS source is not involved in the 'request' (including application-level or OS-level caching).

Some example network traffic monitoring tools you could use are:

- Wireshark (Windows or MacOS)
- snoop (Solaris)
- tcpdump (Linux)

See the man page (snoop/tcpdump) or user manual (Wireshark) for instructions on how to configure these tools/apps to filter out the items you're interested in.

Comment: This is a better answer than a QGIS plugin, since the rate limit is presumably based on requests regardless of the client software. If clients do their own caching (e.g. I'm fairly sure QGIS does) then this is also less likely to give you a false-positive.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Linux, any sniffing tool recommendation ?

Comment: On Linux, I believe 'tcpdump' is the command to use.  On Solaris, I used to use 'snoop'.  I'll add these to the answer.